# Storing short term user data on server

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm implementing a web app in Node.js, a new framework to me. In the app, we pair users together and they share "game data" for the duration of the game. Both users need to be able to query for the current state, push updates to the game state, and recieve updates on the game state. I can do all the event stuff with sockets, but I'm a bit unsure about the proper way to store this data on the server.

I see Node.js has variables that can be accessed from all connections. Would maybe using a global object with unique session IDs as keys and game states and values be viable? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a persistent data store, like a database. If you just use a variable, it could change if the server needs to restart. I recommend MongoDB to get started. It is fast and easy to use when getting started.

[MongoDB NodeJS](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html)

There are other options like Redis, and many more.